# Problem building C# / .NET Core 3.1 solution in azure agent pipeline that uses a netstandard 2.0 package

Tags: c#, azure

I'm having a problem building my C# solution in an Azure Microsoft Agent "windows-default" (Windows with Visual Studio 2022). On my PC, I could build the solution using Visual Studio 2022, but in Azure, I get a lot of errors like these:

```
2023-07-24T16:31:26.9143960Z Package System.Diagnostics.EventLog 4.7.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package System.Diagnostics.EventLog 4.7.0 supports:
2023-07-24T16:31:26.9144942Z   - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
2023-07-24T16:31:26.9145369Z   - net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2)
2023-07-24T16:31:26.9145986Z   - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

2023-07-24T15:53:57.3643861Z     Package Topshelf 4.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Topshelf 4.3.0 supports:
2023-07-24T15:53:57.3644513Z       - net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2)
2023-07-24T15:53:57.3644975Z       - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
2023-07-24T15:53:57.3645521Z     One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.
```

My project uses .NET Core 3.1, but I changed to new versions to .NET 6, and I'm getting the same problems. From what I read, I can use .NET Standard 2.0 packages in my .NET Core 3.1 app, and on my PC, it is working, but it isn't working on Azure agent.

**Solved**
I could solve the problem updating nuget to 6.6.0 version.

Comment: For the EventLog, you probably need [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.EventLog/), which is compatible with .NET Core.

Comment: See [here](https://medium.com/@jackwild/net-core-windows-services-with-topshelf-74e8bfc3315e) for some information about using Topshelf with .NET Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** I could solve the problem updating nuget to 6.6.0 version.